# Heatmap multiple data labels for the same axis in dynamic way using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, highcharts, heatmap

I get data set from back end api, it will have multiple data labels for the same x and y-axis.How can i achieve this for 'n' values.

I tried with 1,2, and 4 it was working. But not sure if it is the right approach and how can i achieve for 'n'values adjusting row size and col size.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'heatmap',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 80,
    plotBorderWidth: 1
  },


  title: {
    text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
  },

  xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura']
  },

  yAxis: {
    categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
    title: null,
    min: 0
  },

  colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minColor: '#FFFFFF',
    maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
  },

  legend: {
    align: 'right',
    layout: 'vertical',
    margin: 0,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 25,
    symbolHeight: 280
  },


  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 1,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: '#000000'
      },
      states: {
        inactive: {
          opacity: 1
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Sales per employee',
    data: [
      [0, 1, 19],
      [0, 2, 8],
      [0, 3, 24],
      [0, 4, 67],
      [1, 0, 92],
      [9, 4, 91]
    ]
  }, {
    rowsize: 0.5,
    colsize: 0.5,
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
    data: [
      [-0.25, 0.25, 70],
      [0.25, 0.25, 60],
      [-0.25, -0.25, 65],
      [0.25, -0.25, 34]
    ]
  }]

});
```

Above is the sample code

Comment: Hi @Sai Prasad, Do you want to show separate points for the same `x` and `y` value or only multiple `dataLabels`? Maybe it's enough to show overlapping points only in a tooltip?

Comment: I have to show multiple datalabels but not overlapping. If there are too many datalabels can display on tooltip but not overlapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your idea is quite good, but to align points easier, you can create only columns or rows.

[image]

I created a function below that creates new series for points with the same `x` and `y` values and align them in one row.

```
function getSeries(data) {
    var i = 0,
        k,
        dataLength,
        movement,
        index = 0,
        colSize,
        limitVal,
        series = [{
            data: []
        }],
        newSeries;


    for (i; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (
            data[i + 1] &&
            data[i][0] === data[i + 1][0] &&
            data[i][1] === data[i + 1][1]
        ) {
            if (newSeries) {
                newSeries.data.push(data[i]);
            } else {
                newSeries = {
                    data: [data[i]]
                }
            }

        } else {
            if (newSeries) {
                newSeries.data.push(data[i]);
                dataLength = newSeries.data.length;
                newSeries.colsize = colSize = 1 / newSeries.data.length;

                movement = dataLength % 2 ? 0 : colSize / 2;

                limitVal = colSize * Math.floor(dataLength / 2) - movement;

                for (k = -limitVal; k <= limitVal; k += colSize) {
                    newSeries.data[index][0] += k;
                    index++;
                }

                series.push(newSeries);
                index = 0;
                newSeries = null;

            } else {
                series[0].data.push(data[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return series
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,

    series: getSeries(data)
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9Ltxcgn6/

Comment: Thanks a ton. This is what exactly I wanted. You are amazing. Thanks for your time once again.